# adjusting Timer period as it is in use, RCLCPP

Tags: ros2, rclcpp, timer

I am using a rclcpp Timer, namely:

rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer = this->create_wall_timer(100m, std::bind(&MyTimerProg::timer_callback, this));

I would like to adjust the timer period as it is running.

This is possible, while using ros2 with python.

I need some kind of adjustable timer, in which I need to only adjust the frequency +/- 1%

I have looked over to https://docs.ros.org/en/ros2_packages/rolling/api/rclcpp/generated/classrclcpp_1_1TimerBase.html and understand ths is not possible. Some methods are defined to cancel or reset the timer, but none to adjust the period.

Could there be any workarounds, or maybe use different kind of timer?

Any ideas/recomendations/help greatly appreciated

Best Regards,
C.A.